# append the query with custom data modifications to add more

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table where i am getting 10 records, out of those 10 records, one of the record has a value of 0 or -110 & 3, those two records have the same ID, so i want to remove those 3 rows from the query itself and then add the following condition just after those has been removed

```
AND DATEDIFF(day, ddate, GETDATE()) >= 21
```

so consider my query has a sample data of like this

This is the query which derives the table data:

```
select id,name,counts,section,skid,ddate from mytable;


<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>counts</th>
    <th>section</th>
    <th>skid</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Jeremy</td>
    <td>0B4C96F0-AACE-5EC1-DA8B-A1F108804751</td>
    <td>-100</td>
    <td>84</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Harrison</td>
    <td>986777D5-EAB3-5C72-A0B1-DE193A9D8102</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>84</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Maia</td>
    <td>C401BA2E-086D-79EA-D230-2D1F55E3ECE9</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>84</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Porter</td>
    <td>8C01AF11-F0E7-C843-0526-8D2549DB7DA7</td>
    <td>1669011652099</td>
    <td>47</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Glenna</td>
    <td>B3299BC5-EA12-4F44-80E8-7331B79CF0D7</td>
    <td>1669030858599</td>
    <td>70</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Nerea</td>
    <td>AF4EDD7C-A78F-2432-947E-A80B2B921713</td>
    <td>1647051538999</td>
    <td>44</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Ulric</td>
    <td>3C630CD8-48F4-4D3E-5AFB-422F0664413B</td>
    <td>1674070698799</td>
    <td>47</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>Haley</td>
    <td>130BC961-B088-C5F9-106B-3C4EAF17359E</td>
    <td>1698091609199</td>
    <td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>Dieter</td>
    <td>DD6DC447-B9A0-587D-D8CD-69ED71AE8967</td>
    <td>1600010948999</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Ariel</td>
    <td>DC6C1F2F-BB82-4E0B-A721-9970034BC07F</td>
    <td>1644031708599</td>
    <td>28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>Nero</td>
    <td>542EEC9D-4D54-E6B0-16E7-14D3739DCD58</td>
    <td>1629091067899</td>
    <td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Brody</td>
    <td>4D3CCBF7-1559-544F-D3AF-C624EB16F62C</td>
    <td>1681060760299</td>
    <td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>Eleanor</td>
    <td>201139AF-BC57-0929-E8C6-55F67979A3AD</td>
    <td>1679071473899</td>
    <td>93</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>Nathaniel</td>
    <td>9C545A83-0A9B-DCC8-C499-73101900E2CC</td>
    <td>1661082853199</td>
    <td>79</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>Erasmus</td>
    <td>6D8A578D-3D6D-57A0-E13A-CCF3E217967C</td>
    <td>1633021494299</td>
    <td>22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>Ocean</td>
    <td>8777AC50-DF94-D5E6-9BA7-33D46C308E0B</td>
    <td>1646060491099</td>
    <td>84</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>Davis</td>
    <td>5513033D-4027-2F35-F041-9CAB1CFEDF5B</td>
    <td>1604042329999</td>
    <td>49</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>Dylan</td>
    <td>1632F874-F5FF-76BA-A5E4-71CF3A49F447</td>
    <td>1654112964999</td>
    <td>64</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>Sydney</td>
    <td>F405C793-9CD0-7522-3815-1AF5F6ED3EEE</td>
    <td>1651092172699</td>
    <td>36</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Uriah</td>
    <td>9C689833-F56B-A2BF-83CA-8482A2DDAE73</td>
    <td>1612082112199</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>Colt</td>
    <td>E04E8A54-0614-D4B0-DA1B-6F3793A2F9B9</td>
    <td>1620092569699</td>
    <td>17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Nichole</td>
    <td>344EA952-03B0-6B3F-9BD9-4A2A33B21969</td>
    <td>1625062523899</td>
    <td>19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Grant</td>
    <td>F4079717-1B11-A222-7896-75EBD5415199</td>
    <td>1616100287299</td>
    <td>22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>8C9B0252-EA63-C7FE-3E08-ED85746F05C6</td>
    <td>1652101578299</td>
    <td>78</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Vernon</td>
    <td>77B6F222-6508-E34C-8B05-F92447FB295D</td>
    <td>1650042574699</td>
    <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>Hamish</td>
    <td>866DBCE3-754B-2CF7-29BB-CCEFBE3F51CE</td>
    <td>1691092777899</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>Paloma</td>
    <td>A3AB2268-9F3E-59B6-570C-8CB3CFEFDC4F</td>
    <td>1695032198499</td>
    <td>39</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>Indigo</td>
    <td>751A36C1-3BA6-4696-21F4-9A86F429F26F</td>
    <td>1638101107199</td>
    <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>Caldwell</td>
    <td>00FB952F-2942-9AE0-F135-9544BCC231EF</td>
    <td>1666081161399</td>
    <td>62</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>Addison</td>
    <td>577752CB-B698-0F39-C088-38239FBC4175</td>
    <td>1666120504499</td>
    <td>35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>Zeph</td>
    <td>E3D1BED8-E83E-705C-0B49-C944885EDDD9</td>
    <td>1613070119299</td>
    <td>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>Leah</td>
    <td>24A03760-1359-F74A-9993-400CA74989E0</td>
    <td>1671100721999</td>
    <td>69</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>Harlan</td>
    <td>DA71BC34-C887-5240-87F7-AFDB62FCEBEF</td>
    <td>1634061625699</td>
    <td>73</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>Barbara</td>
    <td>15566CAB-1612-9CE6-AA2C-689370B716B7</td>
    <td>1641120968899</td>
    <td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>Arden</td>
    <td>CC14D9E6-1A42-91E7-51ED-EBB07D1893BB</td>
    <td>1631020829599</td>
    <td>81</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>Rylee</td>
    <td>6EAD8D4C-0772-890B-2777-11BF39118699</td>
    <td>1661100717699</td>
    <td>58</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>Keegan</td>
    <td>99C05F56-D2D5-BE91-9096-A0EC862978F7</td>
    <td>1678023087399</td>
    <td>84</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>Lee</td>
    <td>FD008FE6-9DEB-7C23-A1A5-B302F2BAB9D3</td>
    <td>1681032241999</td>
    <td>19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>Mia</td>
    <td>9DDD3D31-1F83-1773-4EF1-6C8A227B0D13</td>
    <td>1620031462299</td>
    <td>97</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>Colt</td>
    <td>27699409-B83A-0136-2833-E021DF5BD4B4</td>
    <td>1650072467399</td>
    <td>63</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>Abdul</td>
    <td>80D98E0D-0594-7149-0771-48C53F763020</td>
    <td>1621111858399</td>
    <td>71</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>Jana</td>
    <td>F5D63E7A-8D87-765C-211A-125A722CD307</td>
    <td>1600100835399</td>
    <td>82</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>C345760F-8C61-DF91-D65A-DFEC171CA098</td>
    <td>1641040266599</td>
    <td>72</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>Evangeline</td>
    <td>56E4C39A-5534-3752-72D6-A0DB1A9367BE</td>
    <td>1653060725799</td>
    <td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>Keelie</td>
    <td>A5E9377C-B4D9-6FA3-0543-DE6038D793D1</td>
    <td>1676010796399</td>
    <td>58</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>Carson</td>
    <td>31E2BE9C-B2DE-54EF-FF99-000E047048FF</td>
    <td>1627122285599</td>
    <td>30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>Kasper</td>
    <td>5B074C3A-A230-4608-EFBF-A8E9CD3FE266</td>
    <td>1650101362399</td>
    <td>90</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>Tate</td>
    <td>E99105AF-8DFE-EE94-9E58-8F982CAFBA55</td>
    <td>1659060933899</td>
    <td>14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>49</td>
    <td>Mechelle</td>
    <td>D77F0060-87A6-61AD-F178-C8D7B3845FC0</td>
    <td>1668111980499</td>
    <td>24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>Pamela</td>
    <td>F8583251-6DE0-A1FA-2187-70597B4CD404</td>
    <td>1628121968099</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>Fletcher</td>
    <td>57313BC1-BCCD-137E-33FF-BB067DB56638</td>
    <td>1692112615899</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Carla</td>
    <td>CE56A0A8-FD27-F461-5E51-EE5AB573DBD5</td>
    <td>1661032917899</td>
    <td>73</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>Basia</td>
    <td>9BD2CDC6-6B0A-C9D4-DE6E-A4BA28CD6427</td>
    <td>1687041589899</td>
    <td>59</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>Lesley</td>
    <td>CE21D00A-00F6-418C-C9E8-5B09CAD64B18</td>
    <td>1639050475699</td>
    <td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>Jade</td>
    <td>132AE1C1-16E7-63AC-3D8A-B8C23E97813A</td>
    <td>1651082175399</td>
    <td>38</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>Autumn</td>
    <td>E2FA0C3E-B6F3-D40E-5FA6-0CA459C96278</td>
    <td>1690041526599</td>
    <td>84</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>57</td>
    <td>Joan</td>
    <td>B6315225-A567-2DE6-F931-26FF2161D999</td>
    <td>1682022818699</td>
    <td>96</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>58</td>
    <td>Marcia</td>
    <td>4CDB28E7-A449-27C3-3A78-4CDCF905AD07</td>
    <td>1641040720799</td>
    <td>88</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>Regan</td>
    <td>6D93AF43-13C8-0379-04C5-1C56A8930A5B</td>
    <td>1663052343799</td>
    <td>46</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>Christian</td>
    <td>818482C2-9912-BD5B-399B-BEEFE3DCE8D3</td>
    <td>1677020840699</td>
    <td>69</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>Wing</td>
    <td>7746878F-2BE8-7CFA-AD7D-4E9B0D77661F</td>
    <td>1670121897699</td>
    <td>65</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>Merritt</td>
    <td>79FE8FF1-42C4-3FA0-E3BC-51170948FC69</td>
    <td>1672010917299</td>
    <td>44</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>Kay</td>
    <td>D44BA900-07A0-24E8-9000-0D1FF173E5B7</td>
    <td>1677072899899</td>
    <td>53</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>Alfreda</td>
    <td>501006BC-AFE4-046C-20CA-41B4452A2F99</td>
    <td>1676022339299</td>
    <td>67</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>Barrett</td>
    <td>647ED1CB-7B40-81B9-05E3-19A0EEF00840</td>
    <td>1695071106999</td>
    <td>48</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>Edward</td>
    <td>CE31C4D2-391F-8CED-802D-36DD986A516D</td>
    <td>1668100834399</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>Rudyard</td>
    <td>6CF06D57-3019-7B1D-3EA0-2DD297322D18</td>
    <td>1650072406099</td>
    <td>17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>Rana</td>
    <td>487B8EF0-D757-353E-88BD-6AEB7E2A6892</td>
    <td>1649061924599</td>
    <td>71</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>69</td>
    <td>Yuli</td>
    <td>040854F3-5D96-A14C-2D5B-F38E58752356</td>
    <td>1665022089299</td>
    <td>77</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>Debra</td>
    <td>E31EFCD4-CFC6-271B-5E94-764D0A317680</td>
    <td>1682021613899</td>
    <td>28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>71</td>
    <td>Eaton</td>
    <td>0B20B2EA-301E-24C6-B901-80CA984BDAC5</td>
    <td>1692123002399</td>
    <td>66</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>Acton</td>
    <td>F87766EE-273D-E8BC-88EB-4DB0ED6D07F1</td>
    <td>1688081955899</td>
    <td>41</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>73</td>
    <td>Wallace</td>
    <td>02A2797C-E2E7-6E8B-2F54-14422B96EAC3</td>
    <td>1682010642899</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>74</td>
    <td>Valentine</td>
    <td>7EFC2906-5549-C5FB-EA40-75AC790531A1</td>
    <td>1642091417399</td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>Zane</td>
    <td>C10D8142-36D7-D358-513C-34079B93EED4</td>
    <td>1638121063899</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>76</td>
    <td>Addison</td>
    <td>A1426ED4-7ECF-C09A-0541-482DD835D7E8</td>
    <td>1657040512199</td>
    <td>41</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>77</td>
    <td>Hedda</td>
    <td>FCF42864-0F47-55E8-ADC1-2878EB905976</td>
    <td>1679120807899</td>
    <td>68</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>78</td>
    <td>Zeus</td>
    <td>89D8AD53-D477-1FE9-720E-28A54D9748CB</td>
    <td>1615032107099</td>
    <td>93</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>79</td>
    <td>Shaeleigh</td>
    <td>2DF52B59-F914-2D5A-F1FA-C752AF13AC29</td>
    <td>1621010516399</td>
    <td>90</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>791F363D-74BB-51B8-F05F-88E9A3E8D2D5</td>
    <td>1685060734699</td>
    <td>54</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>81</td>
    <td>Chaney</td>
    <td>A843E306-7D2A-90EE-35B1-C6C99C73D5B8</td>
    <td>1651082857899</td>
    <td>98</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>82</td>
    <td>Whitney</td>
    <td>10380818-AB30-501E-BFF3-8647EEC2CD3A</td>
    <td>1620072074699</td>
    <td>64</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>83</td>
    <td>Rhiannon</td>
    <td>FBDBE676-2BDE-59BE-A3B5-6126C278274F</td>
    <td>1620071659699</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>84</td>
    <td>Risa</td>
    <td>CE7C1D86-A526-4AB6-BEC4-BF02880DE498</td>
    <td>1647092989299</td>
    <td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>Hoyt</td>
    <td>C8D5DA43-42A4-9C9C-C954-7DDD0F577899</td>
    <td>1652022451199</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>Cruz</td>
    <td>4AB62FBA-3F65-2F88-8D9D-7DF7A5159C74</td>
    <td>1603091524299</td>
    <td>56</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>87</td>
    <td>Riley</td>
    <td>61E2C7FC-6435-F765-C376-9027981F823D</td>
    <td>1693092567199</td>
    <td>66</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>Magee</td>
    <td>13708277-A251-8C42-E8BD-C0218620F6E1</td>
    <td>1601051836499</td>
    <td>40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>89</td>
    <td>Mia</td>
    <td>2843F1B7-A70E-808C-7B8A-423925548D73</td>
    <td>1693061729799</td>
    <td>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>Solomon</td>
    <td>30828793-2CFF-C962-0ACC-5FC62AECE5F9</td>
    <td>1625060887299</td>
    <td>36</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>91</td>
    <td>Josephine</td>
    <td>C43233D9-F4E9-EF31-9D77-2A913610CEC9</td>
    <td>1644101032099</td>
    <td>40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>92</td>
    <td>Odysseus</td>
    <td>4C4DD636-1403-2B4E-FD2B-36BAC8D7E450</td>
    <td>1626051308899</td>
    <td>28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>93</td>
    <td>Dana</td>
    <td>1FC26C48-5E15-1960-6041-7077670A9199</td>
    <td>1695061049499</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Eugenia</td>
    <td>B11F52CF-4168-C9BC-C5A0-E5F5DBA252B2</td>
    <td>1680102398699</td>
    <td>91</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>95</td>
    <td>Brett</td>
    <td>4C51F8FC-1B90-B1B1-7A79-B34576FE6593</td>
    <td>1635110576499</td>
    <td>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>96</td>
    <td>Quentin</td>
    <td>3B06D55B-2ACC-3926-42A8-80BD159C7062</td>
    <td>1628102018799</td>
    <td>53</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>97</td>
    <td>Mira</td>
    <td>AF1BF61F-DA2D-7332-CCFF-D180420D5017</td>
    <td>1611031933599</td>
    <td>51</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>98</td>
    <td>Adena</td>
    <td>FB963253-D1D3-F1F5-94B0-8E7598D9F03E</td>
    <td>1617051389799</td>
    <td>97</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>99</td>
    <td>Nerea</td>
    <td>09320800-762C-3901-685D-B4DE1D9857CE</td>
    <td>1681032376299</td>
    <td>88</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>Vance</td>
    <td>DF056662-B997-9F8F-A3DB-3283C15B38E7</td>
    <td>1648120830099</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the GIST of the Table

https://trycf.com/gist/26f59ea4fb3cae57cd76ad31c2f604da/lucee5?theme=monokai

my query is generating data like above

so within the query itself i want to remove those 3 rows which have a minus value, the same skid has one minus value, it will remove all its records

and add the above date condition i have to the query

how can i do all this in one sql condition, something using declare, i am not sure

Comment: Post your entire script as well. This will help.

Comment: entire select which one, the sql of the table. ?

Comment: The query you write to fetch data.

Comment: i just updated the query

Comment: So you wants to remove all IDs that has multiple records? Only pick ID with single entry in the table with DATEDIFF(day, ddate, GETDATE()) >= 21... Right?

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cteexclude 
as 
(
  select * 
  from mytable c 
  --Here you are excluding all SPID from selection
  --from MyTable that returns from the sub query
  --by this not in checking, you are getting only
  --records for SPID has all positive Section value
  where c.spid not in 
  (
    --This part of query will return all spid
    --has at least 1 or more 0 or Negative value
    select distinct spid
    from mytable 
    --For example Section calculation is as below
    --Then Do the calculation directly as shown below
    WHERE dateDiff(day,startdate,getDate()) <= 0    
  )
)
--Now select all records from cteexclude
select * from cteexclude;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194322/discussion-on-answer-by-mkrabbani-append-the-query-with-custom-data-modification).